# MATLAB on Ubuntu 15.04: The VideoReader plugin libmwgstreamerplugin failed to load properly

Tags: matlab, gstreamer

In MATLAB R2015b following command:

```
obj = VideoReader('traffic.avi');
```

causes the following error:

```
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
The VideoReader plugin libmwgstreamerplugin failed to load properly.

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);
```

I've installed gstreamer0.10 evidenced by:

```
alexander@alexander-desktop:~/Documents/MATLAB$ gst-
gst-codec-info-0.10  gst-inspect-0.10     gst-visualise-0.10   
gst-discoverer-0.10  gst-launch-0.10      gst-xmlinspect-0.10  
gst-feedback-0.10    gst-typefind-0.10    gst-xmllaunch-0.10
```

I'm assuming I have the required plugins because of the following feedback:

```
alexander@alexander-desktop:~/Documents/MATLAB$ gst-inspect-0.10 | grep avi
ogg:  oggaviparse: Ogg AVI parser
typefindfunctions: video/x-msvideo: avi
navigationtest:  navigationtest: Video navigation test
avi:  avidemux: Avi demuxer
avi:  avimux: Avi muxer
avi:  avisubtitle: Avi subtitle parser
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue. Can you please try the following workaround in this Bug Report?

http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1246784

From the bug report link it appears to be an issue with the GLIBC version that MATLAB uses and what GStreamer uses.

Dinesh

Comment: You absolute hero. I spent quite a bit of time trying to find a workaround but couldn't. 
I'm getting a new error unfortunately: 
`Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
Could not read file due to an unexpected error. Reason: Unable to
initialize the video obtain properties`. I'll link to the solution here when I solve it.

Comment: That was due to missing codecs. I fixed it by making sure gstreamer0.1 was installed and it looks like the only place you can get the required codecs from is specified here http://askubuntu.com/questions/575869/how-do-i-install-gstreamer0-10-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-10/707612#707612.

Comment: Hmm, this site seems to be requiring a MathWorks account just to view the bug report. Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

To work around this issue, replace the version of the library libstdc++.so.6 shipped with MATLAB® with the native version on your system.

To do this, first complete the following steps to ensure that the system's libstdc++.so.6 version is higher than the one shipped with MATLAB®.

1. In a Linux terminal, navigate to matlabroot/sys/os/glnxa64 and type the following:

   ls -l

The version of the library shipping with MATLAB® should be libstdc++.so.6.0.17.

2. Navigate to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and type the following:

   ls -l libstdc++*

If the resulting version is higher than 6.0.17, then continue with the following steps.

1. Navigate to matlabroot/sys/os/glnxa64.
2. Execute the following:

   unlink libstdc++.so.6

   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
3. Restart MATLAB®.